# Get a list of all tables in Oracle Database in Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

how can i see a list of tables in an oracle database in python? Right now I am just having the connection:

```
import cx_Oracle
db_connection_string = 'username/passwort1@server:port/servername'
con = cx_Oracle.connect(db_connection_string)
print("Database version:", con.version)
cur.execute("SELECT owner, table_name  FROM dba_tables")
con.close()
```

which prints out the version: Database version: 12.2.0.1.0

But how can I see a list of all tables which are available in that database?
Somethinglike:
`Salesdata,
Buyingdata`

How can I see a list of all the tables?

Comment: There is no 'python' way to do this - you need to use a query, as shown in your code and answer. The exact query will depend on whether you want to list tables you own, and/or the tables have access to.  Or whether you mean _all_ tables in the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only list of tables (without table owner):

```
cur.execute("SELECT table_name  FROM dba_tables")
for row in cur:
    print row
```

Comment: Or use user_tables if you want to see 'your' tables, or 'all_tables' to see those that are accessible to you even if they are not in you schema.

Comment: this gives me a list of all table names back?

Comment: Yes that will give all table names in all database schemas provided that you have SELECT privilege on DBA_TABLES either directly or with a role like SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE.